# submit button in app component and input in the other component. How should I validate my form On submit button?

Tags: javascript, angular

I have my form in the app component and my field is coming from the other component with the tag name **app-check-form-validation**. How shall I validate my form on submit using both the template and the reactive approach. Please help

Home.component.html

```
<form class="form-horizontal" [formGroup]="registerForm" 
  (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <app-check-form-validation></app-check-form-validation>
        </div>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
        Submit
   </button>
</form>
```

Home.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {FormGroup, FormBuilder, Validators, FormControl } from 
'@angular/forms';
@Component({
   selector: 'app-home',
   templateUrl: './home.component.html',
   styleUrls: ['./home.component.css']
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
    constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) { }

    ngOnInit() {
       this.registerForm = this.formBuilder.group({
           email: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.email]],
       });
    }
    onSubmit() {
        this.submitted = true;
        // stop here if form is invalid
        if (this.registerForm.invalid) {
            return;
        }
    }

}
```

check-form-validation.component.html

```
<label for="email" class="control-label">Email</label>
<input type="text" id="email" class="form-control" formControlName="email">
<div *ngIf="submitted && registerForm.email.errors" class="invalid-feedback">
    <div *ngIf="registerForm.email.errors.required">Email is required</div>
    <div *ngIf="registerForm.email.errors.email">Email must be a valid email 
    address</div>
</div>
```

check-form-validation.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
    selector: 'app-check-form-validation',
    templateUrl: './check-form-validation.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./check-form-validation.component.css']
})
export class CheckFormValidationComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor() { }

    ngOnInit() {
    }

}
```

Comment: You are not building your form anywhere?

Comment: That I will do in my HomeComponent using the reactive approch

Comment: Well show us the code, we cannot help unless we see all relevant code ;)

Comment: can you please go through the code I have updated it now and have added the form in the Home.component.ts file

Comment: How can I process

Answer (score 0):

You could use a service with an observable. The component which submits could call a service function, while the one which validates could subscribe to the service and take appropriate action.

You can read about services here: https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt4